# Javascript Angular4 Service method not recognize

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created a simple service using angular4

Here's the code:

```
//app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MyserviceService } from './myservice.service';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [MyserviceService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

//the service
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

export class MyserviceService {

  constructor() { }

  cars = ['fiat', 'form'];

  myData() {
    return 'Hello from service!';
  }

}

//app.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyserviceService } from './myservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'app';

  constructor(private myservice: MyserviceService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.myservice.cars);

    this.something = this.myData();
  }

}
```

I am having 2 problems here:

1. No console message
2. myData is not recognized 'myData does not exists in app.component'

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: It should be `this.myservice.myData()` but not sure why log is not displayed. Can you reproduce the issue in a plunker?

Comment: So how does the accepted answer solve the `console.log` issue?

Comment: Yes, once I added this.myservice.myData() .. the console appeared too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing `myData()` method on app.component, it is not a member of app component. you have to access `myData()` with myservice, like this

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.myservice.cars);

  this.something = this.myservice.myData();
```

}

and Everything else looks fine to me.